# PropTypes import for React is not recognized on class components

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-proptypes, tsx

I've install PropTypes via npm module and below is a dumbed down version of the code.  Does anyone have any idea why I can't access .propType on my class?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { DataGrid } from 'devextreme-react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: { dataSource?: any[] }) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <DataGrid dataSource={[]}>
            </DataGrid>
        );
    }
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
    dataSource: PropTypes.array
};

export default MyComponent;
```

[image]

Comment: I think you mean `MyComponent.propTypes` with an `s` at the end.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: Sorry that was typo on my part, same error message though. I've update the code and screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you code is fine, just restart your vscode. This happens.

You can check that propTypes are working correctly with something like:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    dataSource: PropTypes.array,
    testError: 1
};
```

You will receive a message in console

```
Warning: Failed prop type: MyComponent: prop type `testErrors` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `number`.
    in MyComponent (created by App)
    in App
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-koxotz?file=MyComponent.tsx

Comment: Tried that several times along with removing and re-adding the node modules and package-lock.json.  No luck, still the same error or: "Property 'propTypes' does not exist on type 'typeof MyComponent'".  package.json has "prop-types": "^15.7.2", so I'm at a bit of a loss for what the issue is here.